# Как сделать проверку на выход из графика?

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста, мне необходимо задать границы графика, и если при табулировании график выходит за границы вывести значения, что тут график не существует.

Поставленная задача:

> Разработать консольное приложение, производящее табулирование заданной
> функции в задаваемом диапазоне с задаваемым числом шагов, а также,
> определение минимального и максимального из выводимых значений
> функции. Но преподаватель сказал сделать еще проверки, мне необходимо
> найти границы графика и как-то их задать, чтобы когда табулирование
> доходило до этих значений выводило значение не найдено.

Решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
double x;
double final;
double Func;
double step;
double max;
double min;
double i;
bool t = false;
ofstream out;

// Проверка на то, что вводится числа, а не другие символы
while (!t) {
    cout << "Введите начальное значение: ";
    cin >> x;
    if (cin.good()) {
        t = true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Введено неверное значение!" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }
    if (t == 1) {
        break;
    }
}
//

cout << "Введите конечное значение: ";
cin >> final;
cout << "Введите шаг: ";
cin >> step;
out.open("test.txt");
i = x;

min = (x * x - pow(2.3, x)) * (x + exp(2 * x)) / (x + log(pow(x, x) + 1));
max = min;

while (i <= final) {
    Func = (i * i - pow(2.3, i)) * (i + exp(2 * i)) / (i + log(pow(i, i) + 1));
    if (Func > max) {
        max = Func;
    }
    if (Func < min) {
        min = Func;
    }
    cout << "i= " << i << endl;
    out << "i= " << i << endl;
    cout << "Func= " << Func << endl;
    out << "Func= " << Func << endl;
    i += step;
}
cout << "min= " << min << endl;
out << "min= " << min << endl;
cout << "max= " << max;
out << "max= " << max;
out.close();
}
```

Comment: опишите более подробно вашу задачу и скажите в чем смысл приведённого кода и что он делает

Comment: @Zhihar, Задание звучит так, Разработать консольное приложение, производящее табулирование заданной функции в задаваемом диапазоне с задаваемым числом шагов, а также, определение минимального и максимального из выводимых значений функции.  Но преподаватель сказал сделать еще проверки, мне необходимо найти границы графика и как-то их задать, чтобы когда табулирование доходило до этих значений выводило значение не найдено. Ну это как я понял суть проверки.

Comment: ну так вот это и надо писать в задании, а не 1 предложение и треш код :)

Comment: @Zhihar, извините, пока еще не могу писать красивый код))

Comment: треш-код - код, который непонятно что делает, я про это. Ок, а теперь вопрос такой - в чем именно у вас проблема то?

Comment: @Zhihar, в общем, основную часть задания код делает, он выводит значения функции, находит минимальное и максимальное значение, но надо как-то сделать проверку на то, что график не выходит за пределы значений, то есть не выводит числа которых не существует в функции.

Comment: вы не совсем так поняли, сейчас попробую написать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в основном ваш код делает то, что требуется, но..

**№1:**

не совсем понятна его первая часть:

```
bool t = true;

// Проверка на то, что вводится числа, а не другие символы
while (!t) {
    cout << "Введите начальное значение: ";
    cin >> x;
    if (cin.good()) {
        t = true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Введено неверное значение!" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }
    if (t == 1) {
        break;
    }
}
```

что это? зачем? почему только для одной переменной?

и кстати зачем так усложнен код - лишние переменные и условия, можно же сделать так:

```
while (true) {
    cout << "enter: ";
    cin >> x;

    if (cin.good())
        break;

    cout << "wrong!" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
}
```

**№2:**

теперь вы строите график (вычисляете значение функции) от `x` до `final` с шагом `step`

Так и надо?

Лично я думал, что надо задать 3 параметра `left`, `right`, `step` - левую границу, правую границу и шаг, с которым надо двигаться

**№3**

теперь касательно области определения функции - посмотрите на свою функцию

```
Func = (i * i - pow(2.3, i)) * (i + exp(2 * i)) / (i + log(pow(i, i) + 1));
```

в ней есть

1. логарифм, у которого есть определённая область определения,
2. знаменатель, у которого тоже есть особая точка
3. `x^x` (`pow(i, i)`) у которой тоже не все так просто

простой пример - надо построить график функции `y = sqrt(x)` между точками `-10..+10`, а функция существует только в точках `0..`, значит остальные точки `-10..0` надо пропустить

теперь понятно что вам надо сделать?

вам надо определить область определения вашей функции и скорректировать `left`, `right`, которые ввел пользователь

**№4**

ну и зачем усложнять код всякими `while` когда у вас есть `for`:

```
for (double x = left; x <= right; x+= step)
```

Comment: Первая часть нужна, чтобы если вводились отличные от чисел символы, то есть буквы там, запятые, выдавало ошибку

Comment: Хорошо, попробую разобраться, а не подскажете, как можно еще сделать проверки на целые число, чтобы переменные left,right только целые, а step, может быть и дробным и целым

Comment: да, но ваш код работает только на вводе 1 переменной, а у вас их несколько - поэтому мне и стало непонятно что он делает

Comment: зачем? если  у ваш шаг дробный и кстати Func гарантированно действительное число, то зачем вам на вход принимать строго целые числа?

Comment: но если уж совсем уперлось, то можете проверить так: `value - int(value) == 0`